# Getting listener error while configuring schema registry with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to run schema registry  server with SSL authentication but while starting the server

```
./schema-registry-start ../etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
```

I keep on getting :

```
[2019-11-29 15:20:13,778] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:67)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryException:  No listener configured with requested scheme SSL
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.getSchemeAndPortForIdentity(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:210)
```

But I have the listeners,broker everything configured

```
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=SSL://<my-brokers>
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/home/ec2-user/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.keystore.location=/home/ec2-user/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=my-pass
ssl.key.password=my-key
listeners=https://0.0.0.0:443
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.client.auth=fals
schema.registry.inter.instance.protocol=SSL
schema.registry.url=https://<IP>:443
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to verify the listeners of the brokers

Then, security protocol itself isn't valid, plus the inter instance protocol of the registry should be https, not SSL

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html

Plus, you have a typo on ssl.client.auth=false, and `schema.registry.url` is a client setting only, not on the server